# Choose MainForm from a list of available forms

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to choose a form (as a mainform) from a list of "available" forms after connecting to the database ? I have a datamodule with 3 'available' forms.No mainform for the time being.Datamodule is created first. Now, I would like to select the form depending on the database the user logs in to, and make it the mainform. Can this be done and how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main form is deemed to be the first form created by a call to `Application.CreateForm`. So add your selection logic to the .dpr file code, and then call `Application.CreateForm` to create whichever form the user selects.

```
// .dpr code
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  CreateMainForm;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Here, `CreateMainForm` is provided by you and implements the user form selection. It might go like this:

```
procedure CreateMainForm;
var
  Form: TForm;
  FormClass: TFormClass;
begin
  FormClass := ChooseMainFormClass;
  Application.CreateForm(FormClass, Form);
end;
```

Again, `ChooseMainFormClass` is provided by you.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the DPR. The first call to Application.CreateForm somewhere in the code before the call to Application.Run will do.

Comment: @Uwe Yes. But you'll certainly need to modify the dpr file.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily do something like that in the DPR.

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {DM1: TDataModule},
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TDM1, DM1);
  case DM1.ChooseForm of
    1: Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    else Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  end;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

In this example you first create the datamodule. When it's created you can use the logic in the datamodule. In the datamodule I made a public function that returns an integer to determine which form to load. (In practice I would not rely on magic numbers)